# "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in." Error when trying to display table

Tags: html, .net, angular, typescript

Trying to understand how to solve this problem. I was following a tutorial and I seem to be doing everything properly but still getting this error.

My web API is working properly when I tested in Postman. I also was getting a error involving CORS which I solved but this is the last error I need solved. Sorry if this is too basic of a question but I cant seem to be able to find a solution online that i can understand.

Here is my HTML and TS file

HTML

```
<div class="myContent">
  <form [formGroup]="viewClientsForm" (ngSubmit)="getClients(viewClientsForm)">
    <div style="text-align:center;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px">
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr style="background-color:rgba(220,230,242,1); font-size:12pt">
            <th style="text-align:left;">First Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:left;">Last Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:left;">Phone Number</th>
            <th style="text-align:left;">Amount</th>
            <th style="text-align:left;">Status</th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let clients of client" style="background-color:white">
            <td> {{clients.FirstName  }} </td>
            <td> {{clients.LastName }} </td>
            <td> {{clients.HomeNumber}} </td>
            <td> {{clients.AssetValue}} </td>
            <td> {{clients.AccountStatus }} </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

TS file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IClient } from '../CPM-Interfaces/client';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ClientService } from '../services/clientService/client.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-clients',
  templateUrl: './view-clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-clients.component.css']
})
export class ViewClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  viewClientsForm: FormGroup;
  client: IClient[];
  errorMsg: string = null;
  showMsgDiv: boolean = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private clientService: ClientService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClients();
    if (this.client == null) {
      this.showMsgDiv = true;
    }
  }
  getClients() {
    this.clientService.GetClients().subscribe(
      responseProductData => {
        this.client = responseProductData;
        this.showMsgDiv = false;
      },
      responseProductError => {
        this.client = null;
        this.errorMsg = responseProductError;
        console.log(this.errorMsg);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template,

You have bonded  `viewClientsForm` variable to `formGroup` property.

```html
<form [formGroup]="viewClientsForm" (ngSubmit)="getClients(viewClientsForm)">
```

`viewClientsForm` is defined but the value is null. That's why angular is throwing errors.

You either have to define a [FormGroup instance](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#grouping-form-controls) or remove the binding if it's not used
like:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="getClients(viewClientsForm)">
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because `viewClientsForm` value is `null`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IClient } from '../CPM-Interfaces/client';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ClientService } from '../services/clientService/client.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-clients',
  templateUrl: './view-clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-clients.component.css']
})
export class ViewClientsComponent implements OnInit {


  // HERE you can do viewClientsForm = this.formBuilder.group({...etc})
  viewClientsForm: FormGroup;
  client: IClient[];
  errorMsg: string = null;
  showMsgDiv: boolean = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private clientService: ClientService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClients();
    if (this.client == null) {
      this.showMsgDiv = true;
    }
  }
  getClients() {
    this.clientService.GetClients().subscribe(
      responseProductData => {
        this.client = responseProductData;
        this.showMsgDiv = false;
      },
      responseProductError => {
        this.client = null;
        this.errorMsg = responseProductError;
        console.log(this.errorMsg);
      }
    );
  }
}
```